# C# filter list based on type

Tags: c#

I've simplified my question:

I've got a list with `animals` in that list I store `dogs` and `cats`:

```
private List<Animal> animals;

private Constr()
{
    animals = new List<Animal>();
}

public void addCat(Cat cat)
{
    animals.Add(cat);
}

public void addDog(Dog dog)
{
    animals.Add(dog);
}
```

Now I would like to filter out only the cats. I already tried this:

```
public List<Cat> getCats()
{
    return animals.OfType<Animal>().ToList();
}
```

and this:

```
public List<Cat> getCats()
{
    return animals.Where((type) => type.GetType() ==  typeof(Animal));
}
```

But both don't work.

> Cannot implicity convert type type Project.Animal to Project.Cat

Is it not possible to filter out one type of object?

Comment: You're filtering it to `Animal` in both cases, not `Cat`.  It should be `return animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList();`

Comment: `(type) => type.GetType() ==  typeof(Animal)` won´t work because the type of the current instance is actually `Cat`, not `Animal`. You might handle this using `IsAssignableFrom` which will return true if one type is the base-type of the other. However there´s already a better appraoch given as answer to you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want items of type `Cat`, then that's what you should indicate:

```
public List<Cat> getCats()
{
    return animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList();
}
```

And the more manual approach:

```
public List<Cat> getCats()
{
    return animals.Where(animal => animal is Cat)
                  .Select(animal => (Cat)animal);
}
```

Note the use of `is`, not `.GetType() == ...`. If you're using `.GetType() == ...`, that's usually a code smell.

Here's a somewhat more efficient version of the manual version, done in the opposite order:

```
public List<Cat> getCats()
{
    return animals.Select(animal => animal as Cat)
                  .Where(cat => cat != null);
}
```